# How do you replace characters in a column of a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

From a dataframe, one column has int64 values and also some '?' where the data is not present.
The task is to replace the '?' with the mean of the integers in the column.
The column looks something like this:

```
30.82
26.67
17.56
?
34.99
?
.
. 
.
```

Till now i tried using a for loop to calculate the mean while skipping the index where s[i] == '?'.
But once i try to replace the characters with mean value it gives me an error.

```
    def fillreal(column)        

    s = pd.Series(column)
    count = 0
    summ = 0
    for i in range(s.size):
        if s[i] == '?':
            continue
    else:
        summ += pd.to_numeric(s[i])
        count = count+1

    av = round(summ/count,2) 
    column.replace('?', str(av))
    return column
```

function call is:

```
   dataR =  fillreal(df['col2'])
```

How should i correct the code so that it works fine, and also which functions can be used to optimise the code?
TIA

Comment: `ser=pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce')` , `ser.fillna(s.mean())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.replace('?', np.mean(pd.to_numeric(df['30.82'], errors='coerce')))
```

30.82 here is the name of the column.

Make sure you have `inplace=True` if you want the dataframe itself modifed. as shown below. you can assign the above statement to a new variable (ex:new_df) and you will get a new df will ? repalce (original remains as it is)

```
df.replace('?', np.mean(pd.to_numeric(df['30.82'], errors='coerce')),inplace=True)
```